# Can you do AND/OR type queries with the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, bitwise-operators

I would like to use AND OR style bitwise operatirs with an AWS CLI query.

Specifically, I would like to find all of our load balancers that are:

1. internet facing (Scheme == "internet=facing")
2. use https (Protocol == "HTTPS")
3. are not limited to just TLS1.2 (PolicyNames != "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01")

If I do a base query for just one of the criteria, it works:

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --query "LoadBalancerDescriptions[].ListenerDescriptions[?PolicyNames!='ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01']"
```

If I try to add to that with one more criteria, it fails:

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --query "LoadBalancerDescriptions[].ListenerDescriptions[?PolicyNames!='ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01'], LoadBalancerDescriptions[].ListenerDescriptions[?Scheme=='internet-facing']"
```

Eventually, I would like for it to output the Name, DNS, and ideally, the CFT it is tied to, but only the internetfacing HTTPS ports that are not restricted to TLS1.2

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out:

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --query "LoadBalancerDescriptions[?Scheme=='internet-facing'].[LoadBalancerName, DNSName, ListenerDescriptions[?PolicyNames!='ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01'], ListenerDescriptions[*].Listener[?Protocol=='HTTPS']]"
```

Still not sure the best way to link it to the CFTs via a CLI command, but getting closer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the pipe operator `|` to simulate a boolean AND, like this:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owner amazon --query 'Images[?Name!=`null`]|[?starts_with(Name, `aws-elasticbeanstalk`) == `true`]|[0:5].[ImageId,Name]' --output text
```

I got this example from [here](https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/07/27/advanced-aws-cli-jmespath-query/).